# Simplejson dumps char \

Tags: django, json, serialization, simplejson

I'm programming with Django need to serialize an object to a string, but I need to get the string `\/` serialized.

An example:

```
simplejson.dumps({'id' : 'root\/leaf'})
```

I need an output like this:

```
{"id": "root\/leaf"}
```

But I get this:

```
{"id": "root\\\\\\\\leaf"}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON requires that the literal `\` character be escaped, and represented as `\\`.  Python also represents the literal `\` character escaped, as `\\`.  Between the two of them, `\` becomes `\\\\`.

Notice the following in Python:

```
>>> "\\/" == "\/"
True

>>> {"id": "root\/leaf"} == {"id": "root\\/leaf"}
True

>>> {"id": "root\\/leaf"}["id"]
'root\\/leaf'

>>> print {"id": "root\\/leaf"}["id"]
root\/leaf
```

Python is printing the extra escape .  So when you do `simplejson.dumps({"id": "root\/leaf"})`, python is printing the correct result `{'id': 'root\\/leaf'}`, but with the extra Python escapes, hence `{'id': 'root\\\\/leaf'}`.  Python regards each `\\` as a single character.  If you write to a file instead of a string, you'll get `{'id': 'root\\/leaf'}`.

**Edit:** I might add, the literal JSON `{"id": "root\/leaf"}` would decode to `{'id': 'root/leaf'}`, as the literal JSON `\/` maps to the `/` character.  Both `\/` and `/` are valid JSON encodings of `/`; there doesn't seem to be an easy way to make simplejson use `\/` instead of `/` to encode `/`.